# Printing area51 pages with the question (on-/off-topic) does not show any questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, printing, browsers

I tried to print the on-/off-topic questions for proposals and it doesn't show the questions at all.

In FF/IE8 I get only the "added" information on the print, e.g. *added by XZ Jan 01 at 00:00* (FF also shows the *add comment* text, nice).

Comment: I think the obvious question is why would you want to print something from Area 51 in the first place?

Comment: @The Propose: I simply sometimes prefer printing out stuff and going through it off-computer.

Comment: Then the obvious question now is why are you so weird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be better now.

Answer (score 0):

Does this [*workaround*](https://superuser.com/questions/120266/how-can-i-take-browser-screenshots-at-a-higher-resolution-than-my-browser-support/120305#120305) help?